# Sum key values in array of objects where a key is the same

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been playing with this a bit and I achieved a working function with one value, however I am trying to achieve summing multiple keys where a particular key is the same.

For example this is my data:

```
let data = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        value1: 1,
        value2: 2,
        value3: 3,
    },
    {
        name: 'Susan',
        value1: 1,
        value2: 2,
        value3: 3,
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        value1: 1,
        value2: 2,
        value3: 3,
    },
    {
        name: 'Kate',
        value1: 1,
        value2: 2,
        value3: 3,
    },
    {
        name: 'Susan',
        value1: 1,
        value2: 2,
        value3: 3,
    },
];
```

And this would be the data after it has been processed:

```
data = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        value1: 2,
        value2: 4,
        value3: 6,
    },
    {
        name: 'Susan',
        value1: 2,
        value2: 4,
        value3: 6,
    },
    {
        name: 'Kate',
        value1: 1,
        value2: 2,
        value3: 3,
    },
]
```

The function I have for a single value is:

```
function sumValuesInArrayOfObjectsByKey(arr, key, value) {
    const map = new Map();
    for (const obj of arr) {
        const currSum = map.get(obj[key]) || 0;
        map.set(obj[key], currSum + obj[value]);
    }
    const res = Array.from(map, ([k, v]) => ({ [key]: k, [value]: v }));
    return res;
}
```

Any help or direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `const sumProperties = Object.fromEntries([ "value1", "value2", "value3" ].map((key) => [ key, 0 ])); const result = Array.from(data.reduce((map, object) => { const aggregator = (map.has(object.name) ? map.get(object.name) : { name: object.name, ...sumProperties }); Object.keys(sumProperties).forEach((key) => (aggregator[key] += object[key])); return map.set(object.name, aggregator); }, new Map()).values());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to specify just a single key whose value you want to add up - iterate over all keys on the object other than `name` and add them to the matching value in the Map.

```js
let data=[{name:"John",value1:1,value2:2,value3:3},{name:"Susan",value1:1,value2:2,value3:3},{name:"John",value1:1,value2:2,value3:3},{name:"Kate",value1:1,value2:2,value3:3},{name:"Susan",value1:1,value2:2,value3:3}];

function sumValuesInArrayOfObjectsByKey(arr, joiningKey) {
    const map = new Map();
    for (const { [joiningKey]: name, ...rest } of arr) {
        if (!map.has(name)) {
            map.set(name, { ...rest, [joiningKey]: name });
        } else {
            const mapObj = map.get(name);
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(rest)) {
                mapObj[key] = (mapObj[key] ?? 0) + value;
            }
        }
    }
    return [...map.values()];
}
console.log(sumValuesInArrayOfObjectsByKey(data, 'name'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#reduce`, using an object to store the result for each key and summing all keys apart from the grouping key.

```js
let data=[{name:"John",value1:1,value2:2,value3:3},{name:"Susan",value1:1,value2:2,value3:3},{name:"John",value1:1,value2:2,value3:3},{name:"Kate",value1:1,value2:2,value3:3},{name:"Susan",value1:1,value2:2,value3:3},];
let key = 'name';
let res = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
  acc[curr[key]] ??= {[key]: curr[key]};
  Object.keys(curr).filter(k => k !== key).forEach(k => 
      acc[curr[key]][k] = (acc[curr[key]][k] || 0) + curr[k]);
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```